# Booting ubuntu with libvirt pass in custom script to be run from rc.local

Tags: boot, libvirt, qemu

I have an ubuntu image that I start under libvirt/qemu. I'd like to pass in a custom script at boot time that can be executed from rc.local. I can do this with Amazon EC2 instances via their user-data.

I'd like to replicate this feature with my own VM's.

Answer (score 0):

It seems my question is the result of misunderstanding. Amazon EC2 user-data is retrieved by an http request to a special static IP.

http://169.254.169.254/1.0/user-data

The user data is probably then looked up via mac-address. So there is no special magic with the user-data being passed in as the machine boots.